# how do i grab item chosen id in popup window

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I'm creating a page that has a button that opens an account popup window, the new window is account lookup page.
i'v managed to open the window but i need to figure out how to get the chosen account from the new window' here is my code:

```
<apex:page controller="AvailableCandidates" >

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function openLookup(){
       var baseURL = "/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lktp=001");
       window.open(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width=600,height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
  }
</script>

<apex:form id="myForm">
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" onclick="openLookup()" rerender="table"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have implemented the below code to get the selected item in controller class.**

```
<apex:page controller="AvailableCandidates">
    <apex:form id="myForm">
        <script>
            var win;
            function openWindow()
            {
                win = window.open('/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lktp=001', '_blank','width=700, height=400,dependent=no,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1,resizable=no', true);
            }
            function lookupPick(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6)
            {
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.ac_lkid}').value = param5; 
                win.close();
                processSelectedAF();
            }
        </script>
        <apex:inputHidden id="ac_lkid" value="{!ctrlVariable}"/> 

        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Process Selected" onclick="openWindow();"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:actionFunction name="processSelectedAF" action="{!processSelected}"/> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: thanx! but what is "!ctrlVariable"?

Comment: This is the controller variable where you will get the selected record id. Please add a variable in your controller. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Solved it!
Can you please explain what you did? i need to figure out why you chose to do it like that :)

Comment: @Eli, if you inspect the element in the lookup window then you will find that function on the anchor tag so, I just picked that function and used in the page to get the selected value. `<a href="#" class=" dataCell " onclick="top.window.opener.lookupPick('null','null_lkid','null','','001i000000f2x7x','Burlington Textiles Corp of America','null','')">Burlington Textiles Corp of America</a>`